# Stuck on Ubuntu Installation & Trial - Started Dispatch Password Requests

Tags: boot, system-installation, freeze, crash

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a decent laptop. I am installing through a USB and had no errors come up during the disk check.

Initially it would just hang on the loading screen, so I then removed splash and quiet from the start-up command.

The very last line before hanging/freezing is:

```
[OK] Started Dispatch Password Request to Console Directory Watch.
```

Any help?

Comment: This very same thing is happening to me with Ubuntu 16.04 on an Intel NUC NUC5CPYH. I freshly installed Ubuntu and after a handful of reboots it started doing this. I formatted and reinstalled a second time and it's hanging here again after a few reboots.

Answer (score 0):

**Add *intel_idle.max_cstate=1* as a boot parameter.**

*(This assumes you're trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 and your laptop has an Intel Bay Trail processor.)*

Source: A [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324618) on Ubuntu Forums.

I ran into this too installing Ubuntu Server 16.04 on an Intel NUC NUC5CPYH with a quad-core Bay Trail processor. I edited boot parameters by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/301931) and it booted all right after that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following boot parameters worked for me on a NUC5CPYH with 2016-12 BIOS:

```
usbcore.autosuspend=-1 processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0
```

You can boot by pressing "e" on the grub boot menu, and adding these parameters to the end of the line starting with `linux`. Then once in, you can edit `/etc/defaults/grub` to add the same parameters permanently:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="usbcore.autosuspend=-1 processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0"
```

Then do a `sudo update-grub` and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with ubuntu server. 
Solved it by accessing accessing setup and changing the OS.
BIOS > Boot > Boot Configuration > OS Selection > set Linux
Got it from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/774563/834400